# Can't make Google Maps Polyline Disappear

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-polyline

I am using the `Google Maps JavaScript api` to draw routes between points.

I don't want the line to appear between the start and end points, nor do I want the markers to appear.

I have tried to make the start and end points invisible by setting `strokeOpacity` to `0.00001`. I have also tried commenting out any pieces of code related to placing a marker, such as `marker.setPosition(endLocation.latlng);`

How do I make the line **NOT** appear, and make the markers **NOT** appear, while keeping the same movement functionality?

**Link to Code:** http://codepen.io/maudulus/pen/yePGRr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polyline and markers are the default display of the [DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRenderer).  If you don't want to see those, don't add the DirectionsRenderer to the map.  Change:

```
var rendererOptions = {
  map: map
}
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
```

To:

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
```

Comment: It mostly works, although it speeds up the load process a lot.